# ArcGIS - Percentage in Census tract to HUC

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, intersection, aggregation

I’m trying to figure out the percentile of demographic value (minority %, poverty %, etc.) per watershed at HUC12 level. I was hoping that I can somehow convert the values from census tracts into HUCs.
For demographic value dataset, I am using CDC’s [Social vulnerability index](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/placeandhealth/svi/data_documentation_download.html), which has population estimate, percentage, and percentile for each of the demographic value by census tract.

Initially, I thought I could use the “Summarize Within” [function](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/summarize-within.htm) on ArcGIS by using Area-Average calculations; however, this doesn’t make sense for what I’m trying to solve since this function calculates the average per census tract within the HUC rather than the total within the HUC.

[image]
Red outline is the watershed boundary. Blue with black outline is the census tract.

Does anyone know of an approach to use to calculate the percentage of demographic value in each HUC using census tract level data? I’ve thought of intersecting the census tracts into the HUCs and merging them back to find the weighted average, but I’m wondering if there’s a more efficient way to do this.